# Prestashop cron jobs for custom module

Tags: php, cron, prestashop

i have created an prestashop module with php scripts.
And i need to create a cron job for my function that will run once daily, how do i do that?

```
function get_orders_from_presta(){
```

I need to call this function everyday at night.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Best would be to create additional file (or better, controller!) in your module directory with something like this:

```
include_once('../../config/config.inc.php');
include_once('../../init.php');
include_once('yourmodule.php');

// ...here you should have some token checking...

$module = new YourModule();
$module->yourFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

Prestashop standard way:

You have to add a frontController to your module.

Follow docs: https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/controllers/front-controllers/